# JaxB unmarshalling - create Reference to Object

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, jaxb, unmarshalling

Greetings fellow programmers!

I am having a major problem while unmarshalling xml to an object. I need to a create a reference to an object. How can I accomplish it? I've tried to use XSL transformation but due to cycle occurence this wasnt a right approach. I am 100% sure there's an easy way out.. Here's my XML:

```
<report>
    <subject>
        <subjectId>1</subjectId>
        <name>John</name>
        <surname>Doe</surname>
    </subject>
    <subject>
        <subjectId>2</subjectId>
        <name>Frank</name>
        <surname>Timothy</surname>
    </subject>
    <individual>
        <individualId>10</individualId>
        <name>Isaac</name>
        <surname>Newton</surname>
        <co-worker>
            <subject>
                <subjectId>1</subjectId>
                <inXml>true</inXml>
            </subject>
            <subject>
                <subjectId>2</subjectId>
                <inXml>true</inXml>
            </subject>
        </co-worker>
    </individual>

    <owner>
        <subject>
            <subjectId>2</subjectId>
            <inXml>true</inXml>
        </subject>
        <share>100</share>
    </owner>
</report>
```

I need to create reference of "subject" or "individual" with inXml=true. This flag tells me wether we have got entity with that ID in the XML.
Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@XmlID`/`@XmlIDREF` to map key based relationships in your XML document.

**Example**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html

Comment: that won't help, bcoz I dont know where this "reference" will occure.
If "subject" appears for the very 1st time in the XML, it is put all of the data, if it appears 2+, there's a flag inXml + ID

Comment: @MironBe - The following may be what you are looking for:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mixing-nesting-and-references-with.html

Comment: I believe that's what I need.. but how can I find certain subject and get its ID? The XML I have attached is VERY simple only to illustrate the problem - in real life, I am recieving over 300kb of data with MANY nested nodes (up to 5 levels countring from root)..and as I was researching the article you have provided - I came accross the problem - do I need to copy all the data from <subject> which is already "in-memory" to new, adapted <subject>?